# How to add less or equal to condition (`<=`) on rails active record association to select only certain data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In general, my report shows Masters. But I need to display only one wizard for this algorithm.

This request displays several wizards on a selected date for a report.

```
  def get_masters_name
    str = ''
    team.masters.each do |m|
      str += "#{m.full_name}"
    end
    return str
  end
```

And I need to display only one master in the report if his start date will be less (but approximately equal) or equal to the date of the report.

This is approximately what this query would look like in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM * WHERE team.team_id and report_date = (SELECT MAX(master.date_work) FROM master WHERE master.date_work <= report_date)
```

report.model:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'reports'
  belongs_to :team, foreign_key: 'teams_id'

  def get_masters_name
    str = ''
    team.masters.each do |m|
      str += "#{m.full_name}"
    end
    return str
  end
end
```

Comment: Not nearly enough context to help you here. Provide more detail.

Comment: Are you asking how to add a condition on masters start_date (Master field)with report_date (Report field)? While fetching `team.masters` ?

Comment: @PramodShinde Yes, how to add such a condition

Comment: @Matt updated question

Comment: team.masters.where('masters.work_date <= ?', report_date).each do |m| ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a where clause to filter master records based on reports report_date as additionally you can refactor you code using pluck and join

```
def get_masters_name
  team.masters.where('start_date <= ?', self.report_date)
    .order(start_date: :desc)
    .limit(1).pluck(:full_name).join(',')
end
```

Here `start_date` should be the column of `masters` and `report_date` is column of `reports` table.

Comment: But if `start_date`  a lot of dates less than the date of the `report_date`, several `masters` will appear

Comment: And in this case I need to display only one who has the most date equal to or the same as the date of the report (`report_date`).

Comment: Okay, thanks, I understood the meaning of how to do it, then I'll figure it out myself

Comment: If you are interested in only one master record you can order by start date and limit 1, to get most recent master record. check my updated answer